# Unresolved reference: preferencesKey Android Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datastore

I'm trying to store boolean in DataStore.

```
class OnboardingPrefs(val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        const val ON_BOARDING_PREFS = "on_boarding_prefs"
        const val ONBOARD_KEY = "onBoard"

    }

    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
        name = ON_BOARDING_PREFS
    )

    suspend fun saveOnboarding(save: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[preferencesKey<Boolean>(ONBOARD_KEY)] = save
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is preferencesKey cannot be resolved.

Gradle:

> implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'

Comment: Are you adding the relevant import? (I don't know Android, but a quick web search suggests it should be `import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.preferencesKey`.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `preferencesKey`. You can use `booleanPreferencesKey` instead.

```
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.booleanPreferencesKey

suspend fun saveOnboarding(save: Boolean) {
    context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        preferences[booleanPreferencesKey(ONBOARD_KEY)] = save
    }
}
```